# Why picat says that the model is unsatisfiable?

Tags: minizinc, picat

The `picat` solver (v. `2.6#2`) states that the example model `knights.mzn` contained in the minizinc repository and hereby copy-and-pasted:

```
% RUNS ON mzn20_fd
% RUNS ON mzn-fzn_fd
% RUNS ON mzn20_mip
% knights.mzn
% Ralph Becket
% vim: ft=zinc ts=4 sw=4 et
% Tue Aug 26 14:24:28 EST 2008
%
% Find a closed knight's tour of a chessboard (every square is visited exactly
% once, the tour forms a loop).

include "globals.mzn";

    % n is the length of side of the chessboard.
    %
int: n = 6;

    % The ith square (r, c) on the path is given by p[i] = (r - 1) * n + c.
    %
int: nn = n * n;
set of int: sq = 1..nn;
array [sq] of var sq: p;

set of int: row = 1..n;
set of int: col = 1..n;

    % Break some symmetry by specifying the first and last moves.
    %
constraint p[1]  = 1;
constraint p[2]  = n + 3;
constraint p[nn] = 2 * n + 2;

    % All points along the path must be unique.
    %
constraint alldifferent(p);

array [sq] of set of sq: neighbours =
    [   { n * (R - 1) + C
        |
            i in 1..8,
            R in {R0 + [-1, -2, -2, -1,  1,  2,  2,  1][i]},
            C in {C0 + [-2, -1,  1,  2,  2,  1, -1, -2][i]}
            where R in row /\ C in col
        }
    |   R0 in row, C0 in col
    ];

constraint forall (i in sq where i > 1) (p[i] in neighbours[p[i - 1]]);

solve
    :: int_search(
        p,
        input_order,
        indomain_min,
        complete
    )
    satisfy;
% It has been observed that Warnsdorf's heuristic of choosing the next
% square as the one with the fewest remaining neighbours leads almost 
% directly to a solution.  How might we express this in MiniZinc?

output ["p = " ++ show(p) ++ ";\n"];

% Invert the path to show the tour.
% 
% array [sq] of var sq: q;
% 
% constraint forall (i in sq) (q[p[i]] = i);
% 
% output  [   show(q[i]) ++ if i mod n = 0 then "\n" else " " endif
%         |   i in sq
%         ] ++
%         [   "\n"
%         ];
```

is unsatisfiable:

```
~$ mzn2fzn knights.mzn
~$ picat tools/picat/fzn_picat_cp.pi knights.fzn
% solving(knights.fzn)
% loading knights.fzn
=====UNSATISFIABLE=====

~$ mzn2fzn knights.mzn
~$ picat tools/picat/fzn_picat_sat.pi knights.fzn
% solving(knights.fzn)
% loading knights.fzn
=====UNSATISFIABLE=====
```

Every other `MiniZinc` solver, except for `fzn2smt` based on `Yices` (v. `2.2.1`), tells me that the model is satisfiable.

**Q:** is this a bug in the software or a specimen of an unsupported formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason Picat fails on this model is that it - or rather the generated FlatZinc model - contain "var set" variables (see below), and those are not supported in Picat.

```
var set of 1..36: X_INTRODUCED_36_ ::var_is_introduced :: is_defined_var;
var set of 1..36: X_INTRODUCED_38_ ::var_is_introduced :: is_defined_var;
var set of 1..36: X_INTRODUCED_39_ ::var_is_introduced :: is_defined_var;
```

Ideally, Picat should give a better error message, such as "set variables are not supported".

Note that set variables is not supported by many FlatZinc solvers. For example Chuffed throws this nice message on the model:

```
Error: LazyGeoff: set variables not supported in line no. 72
```

Solvers that do not support set variables natively can include the `nosets` file from the standard library. This file will ensure that all set variables are translated into multiple Boolean variables. Ideally this file would be included in the solver MiniZinc `redefinitions.mzn` file, but you can always include this file directly from your model by adding the following line:

```
include "nosets.mzn";
```

Comment: Thank you. An error message would be better indeed.

Comment: @hakank @PatrickTrentin The inclusion of `include "nosets.mzn";` will translate all set variables into multiple boolean variables. It can be added to a model or to the redefinition file in the solver library. Picat could consider doing this. Solver like chuffed, CBC, Gurobi use it and it seems to translate well.

Comment: @Dekker1 Thanks! I've another question: is that include used in the minizinc competition?

Comment: No, but the specifications for models used in the MiniZinc challenge state that only boolean and integer variables can be used. Due to the limited support of floating point and set variables, these are not included in the challenge